# Update one field in mongoose model (node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema where I want to update some info, like this.

```
User.findOne({_id: idd}, function(err, usr){
   usr.info = "some new info";
   usr.save(function(err) {
   });
});
```

But the model has a hook on save to hash the password

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.password && this.password.length > 6) {
        this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
        this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
    }

    next();
});
```

Now when I try to save it takes the allready hased password and hash it again, any idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use [Model.Update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) and move the creation of a new password to an independent function.

```
var salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');;
var newPassword = this.hashPassword("someNew password");
User.update({_id: idd}, {
    info: "some new info", 
    password: newPassword
}, function(err, affected, resp) {
   console.log(resp);
})
```

Comment: The update model is deprecated use updateOne instead.

Comment: what is resp here?

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to use `isModified`?

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    if (this.password && this.password.length > 6 && MYMODEL.isModified('password')) {
        this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
        this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
    }

    next();
});
```